# m_proj equivalent in R

Tags: r, matlab

I am looking for an equivalent function of `m_proj` form `Matlab` in `R`. I am familiar with the `crs` or `st_crs` function in `R` but it is difficult to set the `lon` and `lat` limits.

I am looking to convert the below lines from `Matlab` to `R`

```
m_proj('stereographic','long',-30,'lat',85,'radius',45) 
m_proj('Azimuthal Equal-area','lat',48,'long',-30,'radius',[-105 -45],'rect','on')
```